# How can I execute a command (like copy) for each folder in an Amazon S3 bucket?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have an S3 bucket with roughly a thousand folders. Inside each folder, I want to copy a file to a new folder a level in. Something like:

```
foreach (folder in myBucket){
  cp folder/myFile.abc folder/myNewFolder/myFile.abc;
}
```

How can I execute this one-off logic in S3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using bash and [Amazon's own CLI](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
BUCKET=myBucketName
for dir in $(aws s3 ls $BUCKET | awk '{print $2}'); do
    aws s3 cp s3://$BUCKET/${dir}myFile.abc s3://$BUCKET/${dir}myNewFolder/myFile.abc
done
```

`aws s3 ls` does not include any helpful flags to modify its output, and so I used `awk` to cut off the "PRE" that came with the directory output.

Place the above in `myScript` and execute it with `bash myScript`.